# Why is getImageData only giving data ouput of the first 300 pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

HTML:

The div is for the first four lines of JavaScript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="./colorful_cat.png" id="img">

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

First I get the width and height of the image that I have chosen via the div.

Then in the function I create a new imagevariable and link the source to it.

After that I create a canvas and draw the image on the canvas.

Finally I request the colordata from the canvas from topleft to bottomright.

```
var myImg = document.getElementById('img');
var realWidth = myImg.naturalWidth;
var realHeight = myImg.naturalHeight;
console.log(realWidth, realHeight);

function get_rgba_data() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "colorful_cat.png";

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  return context.getImageData(0, 0, realWidth, realHeight).data;
}

var imageInfo = get_rgba_data();
console.log("imageInfo", imageInfo);
```

CSS:

Does not (yet) exit in this project.

Console ouput:

Outputs only zeroes after imageInfo[1199] (300*4 for rgba)
[image: Console.log ouput]

Btw, this is the link for the testimage I am using:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdiamondpaintingplanet.com%2Fproducts%2Froefpakket-kleurrijke-leeuw&psig=AOvVaw3ipP5DjINR25o2P0thcLPV&ust=1634563635475000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCIDurJ_G0fMCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAH

Comment: you are setting the width and height of the canvas to the natural width and height of the image. For your error, I think the image size would be 300 by 300 pixels

Comment: can you show to console output ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the post!